# Pre-training on a subset and after train again with whole

Tags: dataset, pre-training, generator

I am implementing a Context Encoder on CelebA dataset, due my hardware limitation the whole dataset takes too long for training the Generator and Discriminator, Can I pre-training my models on a subset (1/3) of the dataset and after train again with less epoch on the full dataset? Thank you for your reply

Comment: If you have more data, you certainly can't use less epochs, you might need more. If you are limited by data size, it's best to simply take a random subset of the data, only train on that and ignore the rest. Another alternative is to train on multiple different subsets of the data, and then pick the one whose test accuracy is highest

Comment: I would use less epoch because models should be pre-trained so only to ajdust weights, so it's not a good practice?

Comment: It depends on the data. If your problem is simple and you have lots of data, you might get away with only using a fraction of the data. If your problem is complicated and you absolutely need lots of data to form a representative sample, then training on a fraction of data may yield parameters that are far away from original. Further, standard optimization toolboxes like tensorflow use minibatch SGD, which is already a form of pre-training, albeit with small steps. I'm sure they would be using pre-training with big steps (e.g. 1/3 of data) if it was better

Comment: ok thank you very much that explain a lot of things, cause I have problem with convergence of the loss